# jQuery's sliding functions conflict with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ι am trying to use slideUp and slideDown functions on an element but it seems that there is a conflict when I apply CSS animations on the same element.
http://jsfiddle.net/zgYNg/

On the example above I use CSS transitions on the hover but there seem to be a conflict with the jQuery's functions
The only way that it seems to works is by removing the class buggly before sliding

```
.buggy{
        -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change all to background in your css .buggy

```
.buggy{
        -webkit-transition: background 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -moz-transition: background 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -ms-transition: background 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        -o-transition: background 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
        transition: background 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zgYNg/1/)